# Flutter place object on top of image

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, user-experience

I try to recreate the following image in Flutter web, I understand how to do almost everything, except the profile box that is above the image,

How can I put an object on top of an image?

[image]

Comment: use Stack Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to put widgets on each other ,if you want to put widget on specific position use [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)

i suggest you to read [this article](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/stack-and-positioned-widget-in-flutter-3d1a7b30b09a#:%7E:text=The%20stack%20is%20a%20widget,multiple%20widgets%20on%20one%20screen.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of placing **object** on the **top** of an **image**:

```
Stack(
        children: [
          // Background image placed in the center of Stack
          Center(
            child: Image.network(
                'https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg'),
          ),
          // Blue container 50x50 placed on the top of an image
          Center(
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.blue
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```